# Black Screen in Google Cardboard VR app for IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I created a 3d game in unity and added the google cardboard sdk to my project. I built the game for IOS and opened it with xcode.

When I run the game the virtual glasses (the black frames on the screen for both eyes) are loaded up as well as the thin white line in the middle dividing them up. But the rest of the screen (the view of the game) remains blacked out. The game sound is playing.

I have spent the last 2h or so researching this and found no way so fix it :(

Do you know a solution?

EDIT:

This is the game log when I run the game on my iphone and have it connected to xcode.

```
W1028 13:14:58.468868       1 commandlineflags.cc:1311] Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x103dc9060: no flag found at that address
2019-10-28 13:14:58.543700+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] Built from '2019.1/staging' branch, Version '2019.1.14f1 (148b5891095a)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
2019-10-28 13:14:58.548904+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] -> registered mono modules 0x1039b3710
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2019-10-28 13:14:58.618918+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A13 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2019.1.14f1 (148b5891095a)
2019-10-28 13:14:59.525441+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] INFO [vr/gvr/capi/src/gvr.cc:116] Initialized GVR version 1.170.0
2019-10-28 13:14:59.639509+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] [framework] CoreUI: RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: 'com.generic.bundleidentifier'
2019-10-28 13:14:59.639745+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] [framework] CoreUI: RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: 'com.generic.bundleidentifier'
Created eye textures with a "separate" layout.  The "multi-pass" stereo mode will be used.

2019-10-28 13:14:59.954764+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] [Assert] -[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:] and -[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation:animated:] API have been deprecated on iOS 8.0 and are no-ops on iOS 13.0
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/Uber' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/Uber' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/FinalPass' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/FinalPass' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
2019-10-28 13:15:01.223206+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] [Common] _BSMachError: port 13203; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2019-10-28 13:15:01.239173+0800 3D Beginner Game nofader[6067:1880658] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SplashScreenController: 0x131f037a0>.
UnloadTime: 2.187667 ms
GVR SDK for Unity version: 1.200.1

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)

No controller support on this platform.
Gvr.Internal.ControllerProviderFactory:CreateControllerProvider(GvrControllerInput)
GvrControllerInput:Awake()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

Downgrade your version of unity to 2018.3